# Need to add a font family in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, font-awesome, webfonts, font-family, custom-font

I am working on a CodeIgniter project. I need to add a custom font family in CodeIgniter which will be used in over all project. I have downloaded the font files of ttf, eot and wof. I have added these files in the font folder in CodeIgniter then i have updated the style.css file in asset with @font-face. I have declared the font family name for the body and other tags but it's working I'm not sure where did I go wrong.

**This is the font face I have added in the style.css file in asset folder.**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    src: url('../font-awesome/fonts/Poppins-Black.eot');
    src: local('../font-awesome/fonts/Poppins Black'), local('Poppins-Black'),
        url('../font-awesome/fonts/Poppins-Black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../font-awesome/fonts/Poppins-Black.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../font-awesome/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #888;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a *template.php* file to use all over your project then add your style link in there:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=<?php echo base_url('css/style.css'); ?>>
```

The structure of your project may be like this:

```
/application
   /controllers
   /models
   /views
/css
   /font-awesome
   style.css (you should change the urls inside this file base on your structure)
/system
```

Make sure you load *html* helper to use *base_url* function

Another way is using the html helper in [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/html_helper.html?highlight=link#link_tag)